# jQuery - more elegant way to write the script

Tags: jquery

I have following script:

- it is creating tabs based on number of visible 'li'
- please note this is only the part of the script - I'm looking for shorthans - smart ideas to write that etc..

Can you suggest any shorthand for this? Or more elegant way to write that? Any suggestion much appreciated.

```
    var CoundNumberOfDivs = $('#portfolio-items li:visible').length;

    if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 4 ) { 
        $('.pagination li a').hide(); 
        return false;
    }
    else if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 8 ) { 
        $('.pagination li a').hide();
        $('.pagination li a:lt(2)').show(); 

        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
        $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show();
    }
    else if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 12 ) { 
        $('.pagination li a').hide();
        $('.pagination li a:lt(3)').show(); 

        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
        $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show();
    }
    else if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 16 ) { 
        $('.pagination li a').hide();
        $('.pagination li a:lt(4)').show();

        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
        $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show(); 
    }
    else if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 20 ) { 
        $('.pagination li a').hide();
        $('.pagination li a:lt(5)').show();

        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
        $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show(); 
    }

    else if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 24 ) { 
        $('.pagination li a').hide();
        $('.pagination li a:lt(6)').show();

        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
        $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show(); 
    }

    else if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 28 ) { 
        $('.pagination li a').hide();
        $('.pagination li a:lt(7)').show();

        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
        $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show(); 
    }

    else if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 32 ) { 
        $('.pagination li a').hide();
        $('.pagination li a:lt(8)').show();

        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
        $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show(); 
    }

    else if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 36 ) { 
        $('.pagination li a').hide();
        $('.pagination li a:lt(9)').show();

        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
        $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but it looks at first glance that it would work. Instead of all your `else if` statements, I just use one, and divide `CoundNumberOfDivs` by 4, round it up, and use that in the `:lt` part of the selector:

```
var CoundNumberOfDivs = $('#portfolio-items li:visible').length;
$('.pagination li a').hide(); 
if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 4 ) { 
    return false;
}
else {
    var num = Math.ceil(CoundNumberOfDivs / 4);
    $('.pagination li a:lt(' + num + ')').show(); 
    $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
    $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show();
}
```

I've also moved the `$('.pagination li a').hide();` line outside of the `if` because it's duplicated in your `if` and all of the `else if`s.

Comment: how does this work `var num = Math.round(CoundNumberOfDivs / 4);` ?

Comment: It divides the value of `CoundNumberOfDivs` by 4, and the rounds it to the closest integer. It's actually not the best thing to use, having looked more closely at your code, because you need to always round up, so replace `.round` with `.ceil`.

Comment: No. `round` rounds the number up or down (e.g. 2.6 rounds to 3, but 2.4 rounds to 2). `ceil` always rounds up (2.6 and 2.4 both round to 3).

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to do same trick with other part of the script but it was not very similar so I have failed. `http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/DmFmM/` - any suggestions?

Comment: @NewUser - Again, this is not tested, but it could work (only if `href-*` is the only class on the elements): http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/DmFmM/1/

Comment: sorry - there is another class - .active - for current tab - I does work, but only till another Category selected. Let me put a demo together.

Comment: @JamesAllardice let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2236/discussion-between-newuser-and-james-allardice)

Answer (score 1):

I don't do too much jQuery anymore but here goes

```
var CoundNumberOfDivs = $('#portfolio-items li:visible').length;

if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 4 ) { 
    $('.pagination li a').hide(); 
    return false;
}
else
{
    $('.pagination li a').hide();
    $('.pagination li a:lt(' + Math.round(CountNumberOfDivs/4) + ')').show(); 

    $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
   $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show();
}
```

Comment: Nop, does not work. Never gets to `$('#portfolio-items li').hide();` so must be someting wrong with `$('.pagination li a:lt(' + Math.round(CountNumberOfDivs/4) + ')').show(); `

Comment: That's odd that it never gets there.  On problem might be is I wrote CountNumberOfDivs/4 instead of CoundNumberOfDivs/4.  I don't think that's the issue, but James Allardice's solution looks good.

Comment: Sorry for the typos. Thanks for getting involve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var CoundNumberOfDivs = $('#portfolio-items li:visible').length;
var divisor = Math.ceil(CoundNumberOfDivs/4);
$('.pagination li a').hide(); 
if(divisor > 1){
    $('.pagination li a:lt(' + divisor + ')').show();  
    $('#portfolio-items li').hide();         
    $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show(); 
} else{
       return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into jQuery UI Tabs?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: JQuery UI is 180KB - my script is 4KB :)